# Ruby/Sinatra app not automatically detected (CF v2 cfapps.io)

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am getting a `CFoundry::StagingError: 170001: Staging error: no available stagers` error when deploying to CF v2:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/svaiyapu/cf-env.git
$ cd cf-env
$ bundle
$ cf push
Name> cf-env

Instances> 1

Custom startup command>                      

1: 64M
2: 128M
3: 256M
4: 512M
5: 1G
Memory Limit> 2   

Creating cf-env... OK

1: cf-env
2: none
Subdomain> 1     

1: cfapps.io
2: none
Domain> 1        

Creating route cf-env.cfapps.io... OK
Binding cf-env.cfapps.io to cf-env... OK

Create services for application?> n

Save configuration?> y

Saving to manifest.yml... OK
Uploading cf-env... OK
Starting cf-env... FAILED
CFoundry::StagingError: 170001: Staging error: no available stagers
```

I thought v2 didn't have stagers anymore.

Also, why didn't it auto-detect a Ruby/Sinatra app rather than ask me for a command to run?

Answer (score 0):

Your CF instance seems older than the current head. What release/version are you using? It may be a version which still has the runtime support.
With my latest instance, your commands worked fine and staging succeeded. However you need to add 'config.ru' (rackup file) to start instances. Start-command-auto-detection seems removed when build pack was introduced.

This is for Classic sinatra applications:

```
require './env'
run Sinatra::Application
```

You can also find a sample rackup file For Modular applications at the official page (http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/using/deploying-apps/ruby/sinatra-getting-started.html).